# Recursively query simpler tree-like structures with Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Consider the following data:

```
g.addV('RootTopic').property('name', 'A').as('A')
.addV('RootTopic').property('name', 'M').as('M')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'A1').as('A1')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'A2').as('A2')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'B1').as('B1')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'B2').as('B2')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'N1').as('N1')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'N2').as('N2')
.addV('Topic').property('name', 'O1').as('O1')
.addE('refines').from('A').to('A1')
.addE('refines').from('A').to('A2')
.addE('refines').from('A1').to('B1')
.addE('refines').from('A1').to('B2')
.addE('refines').from('M').to('N1')
.addE('refines').from('M').to('N2')
.addE('refines').from('N2').to('O1')
.addE('refines').from('N2').to('O2')
```

What I would like is something that one gets by using the `tree()`-step:

```
g.V().hasLabel('RootTopic').repeat(out()).times(2).emit().tree()
```

However, this pulls out the full vertex. What I really just need in this situation are properties of the vertex, e.g. the name, such that we get a tree that contains e.g. just the name-property of the Vertex.

I know that if I write `.tree().by('name')` I seem to get a tree with the name as key, but I am trying to find a way which would allow me to select e.g. multiple properties of a Vertex, or e.g. just a certain property having some specific meta-property.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `by()` modulator can take more than just a property key value as an argument. You can also pass in an anonymous traversal which would thus allow:

```
g.V().hasLabel('RootTopic').
  repeat(out()).times(2).
    emit().
  tree()
    by(values('name','k1','k2').fold())
```

or you might use `project()` if you had more complex output:

```
g.V().hasLabel('RootTopic').
  repeat(out()).times(2).
    emit().
  tree()
    by(project('name','k1','degree').
         by('name').
         by('k1').
         by(both().count())
```

The main point to take away here is that with an anonymous traversal you can develop just about any output you would like.

Comment: very nice - got the tree just in the shape I needed. For a novice it is not always clear form the docs how much power the "by()" modulator actually yields.

Comment: I tend to keep the javadoc open for GraphTraversal so that you can see all of the overloads available for the steps - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html

Comment: How could I get the same results in the context of cosmosdb? 
When I try to execute this query I receive an error: 
`GraphSON V1_0 serializer cannot serialize object of type: CollectionField to a primitive value to perform the desired Gremlin step` .

Comment: not sure what that error is. perhaps you should write a new question with more context on the error and what you are trying to do.