# Gremlin find all connected Vertices over n levels

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am basically trying to search all the connected Vertices for a node type, the Cypher query version gives me the expected result, but the Gremlin version is not giving me the intended result. Any thing that I am doing incorrectly??

> Visual Representation of my data

[image: Visual Representation of my data]

> Cyher Query to fetch all the connections

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((n:Process)-[*]-(m:Process)) 
WHERE n <> m 
RETURN ID(n), n, ID(m), m, length(p)
```

[image: Cypher Result]

> Gremlin version

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Process')
.repeat(both().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel('Process'))
.path().by('title')

==>[Cash Processing,Accounting]
==>[Cash Processing,Sales]
==>[Sales,Marketing]
==>[Sales,Cash Processing]
==>[Marketing,Accounting]
==>[Marketing,Sales]
==>[Accounting,Cash Processing]
==>[Accounting,Marketing]
```

**Any idea why Gremlin is not catching the 'Cash Processing'->'Sales'->'Marketing' connection???**

I got a feeling something needs a change in that until() function, but cant figure out what

Comment: It's always helpful to share a Gremlin script that creates the example data when asking Gremlin questions. This allows others to work with your data and better understand your question. See for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038920/recursively-query-simpler-tree-like-structures-with-gremlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't talk about the labels of your vertices, but to me, it seems like the `Sales` vertex already fulfills the `until(HasLabel('Process'))` stop condition.

The correct translation of your Cypher query would be something more like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Process').as('n').
  repeat(both().simplePath()).
    emit(hasLabel('Process')).as('m').
  dedup('n','m').
  path().count(local).as('len').
  select('m','n','len')
```